# symfony, how could I display a form on the base template

Tags: forms, symfony

I want to know if it's possible to display the following form on my base template:

```
$builder
        ->add('name', EntityType::class, 
              [
                  'class' => Category::class,
                  'label' => false,
                  'attr' => [
                      'class' => 'btn btn-info dropdown-toggle'
                  ]
              ]
          );
```

The goal is to display every category automatically on the navbar, without rendering the form on every controller.

Comment: Thanks it worked perfectly, here is the doc : https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/templating/embedding_controllers.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a seprated controller that renders this form and render controller directly in your navbar template.

For example:

```
{{ render(controller(
    'App\\Controller\\ArticleController::recentArticles',
    { 'max': 3 }
)) }}
```